# Simulate join between Hashes

Tags: ruby

I have two Arrays of Hashes which simulate two tables in a database, with one key in the first hash referencing a separately-named key in the second hash, example below:

```
cars = [ { id: 1, color: 'red', owner_id: 1 }, { id: 2, color: 'black', owner_id: 1 } ]
owners = [ { id: 1, name: 'Alice' }, { id: 2, name: 'Bob' } ]
```

I'd like to try to accomplish a "join" on these two hashes, resulting in a new Array of Hashes, so that the keys and values from `owners` will be merged into any of the `cars` hashes where the cars' `:owner_id` matches an owner's `:id`. So in the above example, the result would look like this:

```
[ { id: 1, color: 'red', owner_id: 1, name: 'Alice' }, { id: 2, color: 'black', owner_id: 1, name: 'Alice' } ]
```

Anyone have any thoughts on how I could achieve this? Thank you!

[EDIT] Updated to clarify that I would like the results to be placed in a new Array of Hashes, rather than mutating either of the original Arrays.

Answer (score 3):

```
def join(referers, referees, on_referer, on_referee)
  referers.map do |record|
    referees.find do |referee_record|
      record[on_referer] == referee_record[on_referee]
    end.merge(record)
  end
end

cars = [ { id: 1, color: 'red', owner_id: 1 }, { id: 2, color: 'black', owner_id: 1 } ]
owners = [ { id: 1, name: 'Alice' }, { id: 2, name: 'Bob' } ]

join(cars, owners, :owner_id, :id)
  # => [{:id=>1, :name=>"Alice", :color=>"red", :owner_id=>1},
  #     {:id=>2, :name=>"Alice", :color=>"black", :owner_id=>1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I just noticed that it is the key `:owner_id` in `cars` that is to be matched with the `:id` in `owners`. I assumed the key `:id` in cars was to be matched. I will leave my answer as is, considering that the modification is trivial and that it may be easier to follow if the match is to be on the same key names.

Assuming that:

- you want to modify (mutate) `cars`; and
- for each element `h` of `owners` there is an element `g` of `cars` for which `h[:id] == g[:id]`,

it's just

```
owners.each { |h| cars.find { |g| g[:id] == h[:id] }.update(h) }
cars #=> [{:id=>1, :color=>"red", :owner_id=>1, :name=>"Alice"},
     #    {:id=>2, :color=>"black", :owner_id=>1, :name=>"Bob"}]
```

On the other hand, if:

- you do not wish to mutate `cars` or
- for a given element `h` of `owners` there may be no element `g` of `cars` for which `h[:id]==g[:id]` or
- you just want to improve efficiency,

you could first create a hash for `cars` or `owners` whose keys are values of `:id`.

Suppose:

```
owners = [ { id: 3, name: 'Alice' }, { id: 2, name: 'Bob' } ]
```

We could create a hash for `owners`:

```
owners_by_id = owners.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g[:id]=>g) }
  #=> {3=>{:id=>3, :name=>"Alice"}, 2=>{:id=>2, :name=>"Bob"}}
```

and then write:

```
cars.map do |h|
  g = {}.merge(h)
  id = g[:id]
  g.update(owners_by_id[id]) if owners_by_id.key?(id)
  g
end
  #=> [{:id=>1, :color=>"red", :owner_id=>1},
  #    {:id=>2, :color=>"black", :owner_id=>1, :name=>"Bob"}]
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the hashes at the same position in the arrays correspond:

```
[cars, owners].transpose.map{|h1, h2| h1.merge(h2)}
```

Otherwise, your example is bad.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it bad. He stated he wants to imitate a db join. The need to correlate `owner_id` and `id` is implied.

Comment: @ndn Making any conincidence not look not like a conincidence is bad. If someone says "Let us consider the following random sequence: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...", then that is highly misleading and is bad.

Comment: If he had swapped the order of the two owners, you could have done the same with `[cars, owners.reverse]` and use the same argument. One should not have to think of how not to allow all possible unwanted solutions to work for his specific example, but just enough to be unambiguous. The need to correlate when doing a db join is not ambiguous IMO.

Comment: @ndn Reversing the order is better. If you think that is not enough, having three elements is better.